# How to get the Captures folder back?

Tags: windows-10, screen-recorder, xbox-game-dvr

I record a lot using the Game Bar and it's always been saved in the Captures folder in `C:`, however the video file sizes are very big, so I want to move them to `D:` instead. I read that you can just move the Captures folder as it doesn't matter where the folder is, the Game Bar will still save in there. But I didn't make a target folder in `D:` when I was moving it because I thought the whole folder would just move to `D:` and now the whole thing is gone. (I moved it to `D:\` and not to `D:\targetfolder\` as I should have)

In Settings, it says that it's now saving Game Bar clips to the Videos folder. I want to get the Captures folder back and move it properly to `D:` this time but I don't know how. I tried restoring it from Recycling Bin. I tried resetting the Game Bar. But it didn't work, the Settings still says that it's saving in Videos.

How can I get the Captures folder back?

Sorry for my bad English and thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just launched **Game Bar** for the first time and created a test captrue.

The default location is defined as a sub-folder of the user's `Videos` folder.

```
PS C:\>>Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{EDC0FE71-98D8-4F4A-B920-C8DC133CB165}'


Category      : 4
LocalizedName : @C:\WINDOWS\system32\windows.storage.dll,-21826
Name          : Captures
ParentFolder  : {18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}
RelativePath  : Captures
```

As a KnownFolder, you can navigate to it in **Explorer** by typing `shell:Captures` in the Address bar or a **Run**  dialog.

But if both your `Videos` folder and `Captrues` folder are specifying the same location, the `Restore Default` button may not work.

A relocated Captures folder's path will be specifed in th eregistry under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

by a value named `{EDC0FE71-98D8-4F4A-B920-C8DC133CB165}` with its data being of the type `REG_SZ` -- a string specifying the path.
[image]
So you can edit this value or create it if it doesn't exist via `Regedit` or via **PowerShell** using the `Set-ItemLProperty` Cmdlet:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\' -Name '{EDC0FE71-98D8-4F4A-B920-C8DC133CB165}' -Value 'D:\targetfolder'
```